# Работа z-index'а

Tags: css, bootstrap, z-index

Понадобилось наложить слои друг на друга. Наткнулся на z-index но о его работа для меня "специфичная", в плане того что в [учебнике](http://htmlbook.ru/css/z-index) написано что он работает с элементами у которых postion равняется relative или absolute. В моём случае работает только со вторым (на первое реакции нет).

Html:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="tile">
        <h1 style="color:red;font-size:50px;margin-bottom:0px;">CRYMAP #1</h1>
        <p style="color:white;">X5 / KITS / CLANS / INSTACRAFT / STACK / TP</p>

        <div class="btn-container">
            <div class="link">
                Hello world
            </div>   
        </div>
        <div style="z-index:5; width:100%; height: 30px; background-color:red; position:absolute;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Code-Pro-Bold';
    src: url(/fonts/Code-Pro-Bold-LC.ttf);
}

.tile {
    font-family: Code-Pro-Bold;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(52, 59, 67, 0.82);
    min-height: 300px;
}

.btn-container {
    min-width: 100%;
}

.link {
    background-color: #21262b;
    color: white;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Результат:
[image: как получается]

Видно что красный блок перекрыл блок с текстом Hello world, но вышел за пределы своего блока.
во втором случае у обоих блоков значение свойства postion изменено на relative, но реакции нету никакой.

[image: как должно быть]

Для вёрстки использую bootstrap.
Требуется чтобы красный блок перекрыл блок с текстом Hello world

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так.

```
<div class="btn-container">
    <div class="link">Hello world</div>
    <div style="width:100%; height: 30px; background-color:red; position:absolute; top: 0;"></div>
</div>

.btn-container {
    min-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

Короче, нужно, чтобы оба дива находились в одном диве-родителе с `position:relative` и верхний перекрывающий див был абсолютно спозиционирован. Тогда можно обойтись вообще без z-index.

Comment: Цель в том чтобы красный блок закрыл блок с текстом hello world

Comment: Исправил ответ. Попробуйте так.